How to load gettext catalogues for libraries and application?
It is my understanding that only one single catalogue can be loaded (one .mo file), as per Translation Workflow Overview §5.
The Python example in Finding Message Catalogs at Runtime seems to support this with the assertion that

[a]lthough find() shows the complete list of catalogs, only the first one in the sequence is actually loaded for message lookups.

Likewise, the old Mono.Unix.Catalog does not seem to be able to load more than one .mo file at a time.
When I have one catalogue per library and build my application, presumably I have to use msgcat to merge the .po files of libraries and application into one .po file and then translate that merged file into one .mo file.
... But merging .po files with different Project-Id-Version (which is of course different per artifact) results in a #, fuzzy meta entry with meta information of all so-merged .po files, so apparently this is not the intended way.
Another hint is that e.g. Poedit keeps generating .mo files the moment I just open a .po file, so apparently its use case is to use the partial .mo files themselves somehow.
What is the expected way to present catalogue files for multiple artifacts to a gettext implementation?

Merged .po?
Merged .mo?
Something else entirely?

How to generate it from one .po file per language per artifact?
Gtk-Sharp seems to manage this - it has its own .mo files, yet I can still load my own catalogue normally and somehow the application has access to both.
Unfortunately there does not seem to be any documentation for this. All I can find, whether for gettext or Poedit always talks about having one single .po file (per language) for everything. But not, how to achieve that.
